How to remove CleanBrowsing DNS Filter app that is not shown anywhere?
I installed the free version of CleanBrowsing DNS Filter on my Pixel 6 phone that's running Android 12. I gave it admin access and did the hardening process to prevent settings from being changed or uninstalled by creating a PIN to access the CleanBrowsing admin settings.
Now, I can't find the CleanBrowsing app on my phone and have no way of making changes to settings.  It doesn't even show up in the app that has admin access.  CleanBrowsing customer support has been no help.  I can't access my security cameras on my phone because of CleanBrowsing.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can access CleanBrowsing on my Pixel phone so I can remove it as it's causing more trouble than it's worth?

"It doesn't even show up in the app that has admin access" did Play Protect, by any chance, detect and remove it as a harmful app..? Can you open the Android Settings, browse to Private DNS settings and turn it off manually?

This usually works for me, for other apps.

Open Play Store
Type in Clean Browsing
Select the App
You should see two buttons - Uninstall and Open

